# switch statement scroll value (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a website which triggers different events depending on how far down the page the user scrolls.

So far the logic I've been using is through a series of if statements to check how far down the page the user is:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {

if(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= <insert value or reference here>) 
{
     <enter code here>
}
...
```

I thought it would be more convenient to write this as a switch statement:

```
switch(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY)
{
    case (<insert value or reference here>):
        <enter code here>
        break;
        ...
}
```

but for some reason it's triggering as an if statement but not as a switch statement. Can anyone help me understand why? I would also like to know if there's a more efficient way of doing this or any suggestions are also welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: This could be an option if you are open to using jquery plugins its a great tool,

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "it's triggering as an if statement but not as a switch statement". How do you think a switch statement works?

Comment: Switch statements don't provide much more convenience over if statements. I personally never use switches. If I have to do more than a few checks, I find a way to make a loop do my work for me.

Comment: Thank you for your responses guys, I'm obviously very new to this and trying to wrap my head around everything - so sorry if I haven't explained this very well or I have missed something obvious.

I meant that when I debug with an alert in the <enter code here> sections, I get a result when I use an if statement but not a switch.

Comment: That's very useful Kieran thank you - I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont work because you are comparing `>=` in `if` statement while the `switch` is `==`.  If you want a switch statement, it should be something like below:

```
switch(true){
  case (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= <insert value or reference here>) :
      ....
      break;
}
```

The expression should always evaluate to true or false.

Comment: Thank you!

So I wouldn't be able to have a situation with ---case (>= <value>):

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of doing this since if I'm going to write out the whole thing I might as well just use if statements?

Comment: You could put `window.innerHeight + window.scrollY` in a variable and use it for reference in your switch statements like `var getscroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollY; switch(true){ case (getscroll >= value):...}`. It does not make any difference between `if` and `switch` if it is just a couple of scenarios to compare and fork the outcomes. If it is a lot of scenarios, then switch will be more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#block1").hover(
  function() {
    $("#loc").text("mouse scrolled to block 1");
  }, function() {
    $("#loc").text("");
  }
);


$("#block2").hover(
  function() {
    $("#loc").text("mouse scrolled to block 2");
  }, function() {
    $("#loc").text("");
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loc" style=" position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;background-color:green;text-align:center ">xxx</div>
<div style="height:500px; background-color:grey">this is long content. it requires you to scroll to see it all</div>
<div id="block1" style="height:  250px; background-color:pink;">this is a block of comment. you got here by entering the block</div>
<div id="block2" style="height:  350px; background-color:yellow;">this is a block of comment. you got here by entering the block</div>
```

> I would also like to know if there's a more efficient way of doing
>   this or any suggestions are also welcome.

I would suggest putting content in a DIV, and then using jQuery, trigger mouseover/mouseout events based on that.

Comment: Let's not introduce libraries to code that doesn't already use it and isn't tagged as such. Also, don't post incomplete answers. Some will downvote and move on, regardless if you make edits.

Comment: Thank you for your response, just to clarify it has to be based on the position of the page (how far the user has scrolled) and not whether their mouse is close to the content or even near the browser window at all.